# Node & Redis Application Error on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, redis

I am new on Heroku & Node so please bear with me. I deployed my working chatting app(on localhost) to Heroku but can't open the Heroku app.

Can anyone help me how to fix this issue?

I looked at some similar questions on stackoverflow and did `heroku config:add REDISCLOUD_URL='redis_cloud_url'` and `heroku config:add NODE_ENV='production'` but those didn't work.

---

Here is my heroku log.

```
2015-04-11T19:42:35.568690+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 0244dd7 by MYMAIL@gmail.com
2015-04-11T19:42:38.004491+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2015-04-11T19:42:39.182617+00:00 app[web.1]: Detected 512 MB available memory, 512 MB limit per process (WEB_MEMORY)
2015-04-11T19:42:39.182639+00:00 app[web.1]: Recommending WEB_CONCURRENCY=1
2015-04-11T19:42:39.793252+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:85
2015-04-11T19:42:39.793258+00:00 app[web.1]:       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2015-04-11T19:42:39.793260+00:00 app[web.1]:             ^
2015-04-11T19:42:39.793262+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED
2015-04-11T19:42:39.793264+00:00 app[web.1]:     at RedisClient.on_error (/app/node_modules/redis/index.js:196:24)
2015-04-11T19:42:39.793266+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/redis/index.js:106:14)
2015-04-11T19:42:39.793268+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
2015-04-11T19:42:39.793270+00:00 app[web.1]:     at net.js:459:14
2015-04-11T19:42:39.793271+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
2015-04-11T19:42:40.546881+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Comment: Are you sure that your redis process is running on localhost ?  `Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED` would indicate otherwise.

Comment: I start the server by doing redis-server in my terminal and am able to play with the data in redis-cli terminal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay I know the problem actually, the issue is that you're using redis cloud, so redis is **not** running on `127.0.0.1`

Have a look at [the official documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rediscloud#using-redis-from-node-js) on Heroku; you must not set REDISCLOUD_URL to `redis_cloud_url`, you must let Heroku set it to **your account**'s REDISCLOUD_URL, that you can get by doing this in your terminal

```
heroku config:get REDISCLOUD_URL
```

It should return something like this ;

```
http://rediscloud:password@hostname:port
```

If it returns something without this format then the addon is not properly configured / activated for your app.

And your code to connect to redis should look like this :

```
var redis = require('redis');
var url = require('url');
var redisURL = url.parse(process.env.REDISCLOUD_URL);
var client = redis.createClient(redisURL.port, redisURL.hostname, {no_ready_check: true});
client.auth(redisURL.auth.split(":")[1]);
```

Comment: Also, don't forget actually adding the Redis Cloud add-on to your Heroku application ;)

Comment: Ok. I did follow instruction but still having an error. I think redis part is good now but Socket IO is causing an issue.                                                    Error: Cannot find module 'socket.io-redis'

Comment: Solved Socket IO Issue with server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);

Comment: Thanks Tristan Foureur & Itamar Haber to help me solving Redis issue!

Answer (score 2):

I use Heroku Redis, not Redis To Go and also had such an issue. However I solved the issue by changing the way Redis client is initialized, previously I had following code:

```
const
  redisOptions = require('./redisOptions'),
  redis = require('redis'),
  redisClient = redis.createClient(redisOptions);
```

now I removed *url* parameter from *redisOptions* and then add it to *createClient* method, i.e.:

```
const
  redisOptions = require('./redisOptions'),
  redis = require('redis'),
  redisClient = redis.createClient(REDIS_URL, redisOptions);
```

then the error was fixed. Really not sure why it is working with no issues on my local environment but I need this fix on Heroku.

Comment: I'm just curious, what did you have in your `redisOptions` file?

Comment: @RizaKhan following https://github.com/NodeRedis/node-redis#rediscreateclient you can have different options.